# is there a way to hide a menu behind a div when closed with z-index

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, z-index

i want to hide that drop down menu when clicking the button above it using position and z-index
i did a animation so the menu goes up and with z-index hide it under the nav bar

before clicking

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYs3t.png

after clicking

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVmjY.png

```
.navBar{
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 15%) ;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(197, 18, 18);
    position: relative;
    
    z-index: 1;
}

.profileDropDown{
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 140px;
    /* border-left: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190); */
    background-color: white;
    right: 0px;
    /* bottom: -140px; */
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: -2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

the z-index of the drop down is smaller than the nav so i think it should be under the nav

the closing animation i did this

```
const toggle = () => {
    if (height === '-140px') {
      setHeight('0px')
    } else if (height === '0px') {
      setHeight('-140px')
    }
  }
```

then passing the state to the element like this

```
<div className="profileDropDown" style={{ bottom : height}}>
```

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: i need a way to hide the menu under the background color of the nav

Comment: Why not just `display: none`? Why `position` and `z-index`?

Comment: On click change state and when state changes add or remove class from element.

Comment: cuz i dont want it just to disappear i want it to slide up and go behind the nav

Comment: Then you can use `transform: translateY()` and `opacity`. Like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-firefly-xcqrsc